# Symfony2 and embedded controller

Tags: php, symfony, service

I have a problem with my form service... In my footer (in a layout), I have a form but it not work and I dont know why. Do you how I can call the "createForm" method because the error returned by Symfony2.5 is :

> Attempted to call method "createForm" on class
>   "Dim\WebsiteBundle\Service\QuickContact" in
>   .../Symfony/src/Dim/WebsiteBundle/Service/QuickContact.php
>   line 47.

My service (namespace Dim\WebsiteBundle\Service) :

```
class QuickContact
{

  private $request;
  private $formFactory;

  public function setRequest(RequestStack $request_stack)
  {
    return $this->request = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
  }

  public function setFormFactory($formFactory)
  {   
    return $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
  }

  public function indexAction()
  { 
    $Contact = new Contact();

    # Create the form with the contact entity constraints
    $form = $this->formFactory->create(new ContactType(), $Contact);

    if($this->request->isMethod('POST')) 
    {
      $form->bind($this->request);

      if($form->isValid()) 
      {
       echo 'formulaire valide';
      }
    }

    $this->request->getSession()->set('form', $form);
  }

}
```

My service.yml :

```
services:
     dim_website.quickcontact:
         class: Dim\WebsiteBundle\Service\QuickContact
         calls:
            - [setRequest, [@request_stack], setFormFactory, [@form.factory]]
```

In my layout, I call the index method :

```
{{ quickcontact.indexAction() }}
```

For your information, my ContactType and his entity work fine.

Thanks you all for your help.
Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing things as you are, but to answer your question: you are calling method `createForm` on your `QuickContact` class which obviously doesn't have `createForm` method defined.

You should be calling `$this->formFactory->create(new ContactType(), $Contact)` instead in your case.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply but I again an problem... DO you know how I can sent my the for to my layout view ? (The code has been edited)

Comment: You are doing things the hard way.  Your service should be a controller called from twig with something like {% {{ render(controller('MyBundle:QuickContact:index' %} http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers